# Calculations in DataGridView VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm building a Point of Sales System in VB.net and am using a DataGridView to display my data. When I add up the "Price" Column the total is displayed but if I Press the Total button the number is doubled and continues doubling each time when pressed. Also I would like to know how I could include a button that I could enter the amount received and the change that needs to be given ? I would appreciated any help as I am completely new to VB.

```
          Private Sub btnSandAndSoup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)                          
          Handles btnSandAndSoup.Click
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Bar Code"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Type"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "Price"

   Dim row As String() = New String() {"0037853", "Food", "Sandwhich Soup",
  "10"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

End Sub

  Private Sub btnChickenWings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs
  Handles btnChickenWings.Click

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Bar Code"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Type"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "Price"

    Dim row As String() = New String() {"0037834", "Food", "Chicken Wings", "12"}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)


 End Sub
 Private Sub btnTotal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click
    Try
        'declaring variable as integer to store the value of the total rows    in the datagridview

        Dim max As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim total As String = "Total ----------->"
        Dim tot As Integer = 0
        'getting the values of a specific rows


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            'formula for adding the values in the rows
            tot += row.Cells(3).Value
        Next
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value += tot
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(2).Value = total
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you are iterating all rows: `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows` and the totals row is one of them so its value is added (and re-added) as well

Answer (score 0):

There are two rowtypes - `DataRow` and `AlternatingDataRow`. Loop through and only total when the row is one of these two types.

Put your total controls in the footer template. They won't be added to the sum during the loop.